# Alternative to Friedman test for single treatments (no repetitions)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

I'm looking for a non-parametric (!) alternative to the Friedman test. I have > 2 subjects and measured one quantity per subject. I want to know whether there is a significant difference between any of these subjects. Please note that I used the Friedman test before because there were repeated measured per subject.

Is the Kruskal-Wallis test suitable here? Can you recommend any post-hoc test to identify which of the subjects are significantly different?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you now have independent observations and KW ANOVA followed by any suitable nonparametric technique for pairwise comparisons should be ok. However, what is your classification factor?

Comment: @chl: Thanks. What do you mean by "classification factor"? Here's an example: I have 3 different algorithms which are evaluated on the same data, resulting in three performance measures. Now I want to know: 1) Whether there is any significant difference in the three algorithms at all; 2) Whether there is a significant(post-hoc) pairwise difference. Which test/post-hoc test fits this scenario?

Comment: In this case, I would say that your classification (grouping, independent) factor is the *type of algorithms*.

Comment: Right. Does anyone have a suggestion for a post-hoc test? Is Tukey HSD suitable here?

Answer (score 1):

Dunn's test is the appropriate *post hoc* test for after rejecting a Kruskal-Wallis test. See more here: [Post-hoc tests after Kruskal-Wallis: Dunn's test or Bonferroni corrected Mann-Whitney tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25815/difference-between-post-hoc-test-after-kruskal-wallis-and-bonferroni-corrected-m/95270#95270).

You might perform using the `npmc` package for R, or the `dunntest` package for Stata.

Dunn, O. J. (1964). Multiple comparisons using rank sums. *Technometrics*, 6(3):241–252.