# Bonferroni correction for Wilcoxon signed rank test with 6 related samples?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank, bonferroni, friedman-test

I am comparing scores of the same group of people over 7 days. I first did a Friedman's test to know where the differences were between the 7 days and I did a Wilcoxon signed rank test for the Post Hoc. Is this an appropriate test? I'm also thinking I should apply Bonferroni correction, but should I do this based on how many groups I have, or how many comparisons I make? I'm only interested in if days 2-7 are different from the first day, not if they're different from each other.

Comment: See this post ([Friedman's test is very significant, but its post-hoc comparisons (SPSS) are not significant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175441/friedmans-test-is-very-significant-but-its-post-hoc-comparisons-spss-are-not)) for some discussion of post hocs and Friedman. It looks like some potential references may be Pereira et al (2015) "Overview of Friedman's Test and Post-hoc Analysis" Overview of Friedman's Test and Post-hoc Analysis, Communications in Statistics - Simulation and Computation, 44:10, 2636-2653. and ...

Comment: ... (in particular for comparisons against a single group) Garcia et al, (2010), "Advanced nonparametric tests for multiple comparisons in the design
of experiments in computational intelligence and data mining:
Experimental analysis of power", Information Sciences 180, 2044–2064. I have only read a little of these papers, however, so I can't really say anything about their value yet.

Answer (score 1):

[The discussion cited by @glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175441/friedmans-test-is-very-significant-but-its-post-hoc-comparisons-spss-are-not) has valuable information, but can can be confusing to tease out what the correct answers are.

My understanding is that Friedman test is a generalization of the sign test, so that if you were looking for a pairwise post-hoc, the sign test would be the appropriate one.

Pairwise Wilcoxon signed-rank tests would likely have more power than the sign tests, though my understanding is that the Quade test is actually the generalization of the signed-rank test. You might consider using Quade test as the omnibus and pairwise signed-rank as the post-hoc tests.  It is sometimes suggested that Friedman be used if there are five or more groups, and Quade be used for four or fewer groups.  But I don't have any opinion on this.

[There is also a Conover test that can be used as post-hoc for Friedman's](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PMCMR/versions/4.2/topics/posthoc.friedman.conover.test).  I don't know much about this test, but in playing with the implementation in R, it seems to give reasonable results, and appears rather powerful.

~   ~   ~

For the pairwise tests mentioned above, it makes sense to use a p-value correction method, such as Bonferroni. Personally, I find Bonferroni to be too conservative for most cases.  You might look in to other methods, [such as those listed here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html).

The implementation of the Conover test may need no a-value adjustment.  I'm not sure.

Comment: +1. I agree that Friedman [can be seen as](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83907/3277) a generalization of the sign test. This, however, does not mean that the backward pass, "particularization" of Friedman, yields us the sign test as the proper after-Friedman post hoc. (Neither Wilcoxon is a proper after-Friedman post hoc.)

Comment: (cont.) Imagine a respondent's ratings for X1 X2 X3 X4 are `4 2 7 5`. Friedman ranks it to `2 1 4 3`. Post hoc pairwise comparison of X1vsX3 shows greater distance (2 4) than in X1vsX2 (2 1). But sign test will just say that one value is greater than the other: (- +) and (+ -), respectively.

Comment: What do you think would be a proper after-Friedman post hoc instead of Wilcoxon? Is a Conover better then?

Comment: Conover test is a good candidate.