# Kruskal-Wallis and Mann-Whitney U give different results

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

For my thesis, I am comparing the importance of "comfort" (measured using a 6-point Likert scale) among four groups of people (participants who prefer traveling by plane, by train, by coach and by motor vehicle). However, I get different significance levels when doing the Kruskal-Wallis test and the Mann-Whitney U test.

In the Kruskal-Wallis test I get:
chi-squared = 12.262, df = 3, p-value = 0.006537

When performing the Mann-Whitney U test (with "bonferroni" correction), however there is no statistical difference among the groups:

[image]

How should I interpret the data & is there another test that could give me better results than the two I performed?

May I note that the number of data sets highly varies between the 4 groups (n=272, n=68, n=9, n=140).

Comment: Bonferroni adjustments to guard against 'false discovery' are based on an inequality and are often quite conservative ('reluctant' to find significant differences). So it often happens that K-W finds significant differences, but Bonferroni-adjusted MWW tests do not. // In your case, the very small sample size (for coach?) results in very small power for MWW. // My guess is that your most extreme difference is btw Plane and Train (with sample sizes 272 and 140?). This may drive the KW result, and the unadjusted P-value btw Plane and Train for MWW must also be near 0.01.

Comment: You have not shown much details, so one can only speculate what is going on. If you are free to share more details (e.g, summary statistics for the four levels), maybe one of us can give a more detailed explanation.

Comment: The post hoc pairwise comparison test after the omnibus KW is called Dunn test. It is not just MW but a version of MW.

Comment: [Mann-Whitney is an inappropriate test following rejection of the Kruskal-Wallis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25815/post-hoc-tests-after-kruskal-wallis-dunns-test-or-bonferroni-corrected-mann-wh/95270#95270).

Answer (score 1):

Here are simulated data that may be sufficiently similar to yours to
illustrate my Comments. Likert scores are simulated in R, using various
vectors of preference for the four modes of transportation. If you use
the same seed I used, you will get the same hypothetical data. [R converts
these vectors to probabilities before use in `sample`.]

```
set.seed(2020)
plane = sample(1:6, 272, rep=T, p = c(1,2,2,3,3,3))
auto  = sample(1:6,  68, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,3,2,1))
coach = sample(1:6,   9, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,3,2,1))
train = sample(1:6, 140, rep=T, p = c(1,2,3,2,2,1))
all = c(plane,auto,coach,train)
gp = rep(1:4, c(272,68,9,140))
```

In the boxplot below, widths of boxes indicate varying sample sizes, and notches
in the sides of the boxes are approximate nonparametric confidence intervals for
group medians (calibrated so that *two* nonoverlapping intervals suggest a significant
difference in location). [The sample size for `Coach` is too small for a meaningful
CI.]

```
boxplot(all ~ gp, varwidth=T, col="skyblue2", notch=T, 
        names=c("Plane","Auto","Coach","Train"))
```

[image]

A Kruskal-Wallis test finds significant differences among the centers of the populations at the 5% level.

```
kruskal.test(all ~ gp)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  all by gp
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 8.6787, df = 3, p-value = 0.03388
```

However, a nonparametric Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon (rank sum test) between
`Plane` and `Train` give P-value about $0.012,$ but one version of
the *ad hoc* Bonferroni P-value is about $0.07$ (not significant at 5%).

```
wilcox.test(plane, train)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  plane and train
W = 21863, p-value = 0.01212
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Moreover, MWW comparisons of `Coach` with other groups shows no significant
difference (even without a Bonferroni adjustment), on account of the small
sample size for `Coach`.

```
wilcox.test(plane, coach)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  plane and coach
W = 1318, p-value = 0.6913
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Note:* In these circumstances, my personal opinion is that it it's OK
to declare a significant difference between `Plane` and `Train` because
the K-W test finds 'difference(s)', of which at least this difference must be one.
But I would not feel comfortable finding differences involving `Auto` and `Coach` without Bonferroni (or some other) protection against 'false discovery'.